# passing parameters into a linear search function on python

Tags: python, list, function, parameters, linear-search

I have this linear search where there is a list of words and a single word. the search checks whether the word is in the list or not. I keep on trying to pass my parameters to test the function but when i run the program nothing comes up. it would be great if you could look at this code and tell me where im going wrong.

```
def isin(alist, word):
    found = False
    length = len(alist)
    pos = 0
    while found == False and pos < length:
        if alist[pos] == word:
            found == True
        else:
            pos = pos + 1
    return found


words = ["child","adult","cat","dog","whale"]

if isin(words, "dog"):
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Comment: `found = True` not `==`

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with line `found == True`. It should be `found = True`.

```
def isin(alist, word):
    found = False
    length = len(alist)
    pos = 0
    while found == False and pos < length:
        if alist[pos] == word:
            found = True
        else:
            pos = pos + 1
    return found
```

---

You could simplify the method to do the same task in one line as:

```
def isin(alist, word):
    return True if word in alist else False
```

Comment: What is wrong with incrementing conditionally in this context? (btw, your second version can be simplified to just `return word in alist`)

Comment: Thanks for pointing. I found the `==` missing part later after executing locally and forgot to edit the answer. I have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a lot extra works. Do it like this:

```
def isin(alist, word):
    if word in alist:
        return True
    else:
        return False

words = ["child","adult","cat","dog","whale"]

if isin(words, "dog"):
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Comment: yh we werent allowed to use 'in' in the algorithm but cheers